# Serving gzip compressed files from AWS S3 without CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, compression, gzip

I have compressed my css and js files using gzip as part of my local build process and uploaded these files to AWS S3 bucket. All good so far.

Now, how do I use these files in my actual HTML code? What should be the extension of css and js files in S3.

I kept the extension of the files as is (.css and .js), set the content type as text/css and text/javascript and set the encoding as gzip. I am lost as to what else I need to do beyond this.

**NOTE: I am  not using Amazon CloudFront and need not use as I am compressing the files myself before uploading to S3. All I need to know is how to use the gzipped files.**

Here is what I see in chrome network tab. All good with content type and encoding, but still there is a JS error "Invalid or Unexpected token" at the first character in JS.

[Network Tab output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUxrk.png)

[Error in JS Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpdpD.png)

Comment: Did you check this http://www.rightbrainnetworks.com/blog/serving-compressed-gzipped-static-files-from-amazon-s3-or-cloudfront/

Comment: If you see the images i posted, i have done the exact same thing. Still it doesn't work!